# How can I permanently remove an added alias from zsh (MacOS Terminal)?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, zshrc, zsh-alias

I'm using MacOS and had the issue that my Terminal didn't react to the 'python' command, so I tried out what was recommended [here](https://dev.to/smpnjn/how-to-fix-zsh-command-not-found-python-22j8) (manually adding an alias to zsh with `echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc`).

Turned out this wasn't the perfect solution in my case, so I'd like to reverse it.

I tried the 'unalias' command, but this only works for the length of the Terminal session. If I reboot Terminal, the alias is still there. Is there a permanent way how to delete this manually added alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open the `.zshrc` file using any text editor.
2. Go to the bottom of the file.
3. Delete the line that says `alias python=/usr/bin/python3"
4. Save and exit.

Voila.

The `echo` command combined with `>>` is just appending `alias...` to the bottom of the `.zshrc` file, deleting this line will get rid of the alias permanently.